# Why do we need to give y in sklearn's kfold.split()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

sklearn.model_selection.KFold's split() function takes X and y (y is optional) as parameters. Why do we ever need to give y? All the split() function does is to generate the row indices for kfold CV, so the number of rows should to be enough. Actually X is also not needed. Is it a kind of compatibility issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they want to follow the same format as the rest of the cross validation splits, some of which rely on the X or y data. For example, [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.split) relies on y because it tries to keep the class distribution proportional between test and train data. There's a good visual representation of the different styles [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#visualize-cross-validation-indices-for-many-cv-objects).

So, yes, your hunch was right. It is compatibility driven.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you're right in saying that `y` is not fundamental in defining the row indices when it comes to considering method `split()` of class `kFold` (and actually not even `X`, but the number of samples only).

Indeed, if you look at the implementation of method `split()` within class `BaseCrossValidator` you'll see it actually depends on the number of samples only (see reference to `_num_samples()` method [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1a7cdbf0c540a1136640f3188c89d3703b616dae/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L85) eg; observe, moreover, that method [`_iter_test_indices()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1a7cdbf0c540a1136640f3188c89d3703b616dae/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L103) in the base class is left unimplemented as it is specialized within single classes and it is called by `_iter_test_masks()` which is in turn called by `split()`).

What happens next is that, within `KFold` (and `_BaseKFold`) class, both [`split()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1a7cdbf0c540a1136640f3188c89d3703b616dae/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L306) and [`_iter_test_indices()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1a7cdbf0c540a1136640f3188c89d3703b616dae/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L437) are specialized so as to consider again the number of samples only; on the other side, when it comes to class `StratifiedKFold` for instance, `y` does take a role, as you might see in its implementation of [`_make_test_folds()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1a7cdbf0c540a1136640f3188c89d3703b616dae/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L646) (called by `_iter_test_masks()`).